# Develop .NET application for free?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are Microsoft “Express” editions free to develop on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016436/are-microsoft-express-editions-free-to-develop-on)

Is there software available that allows a developer to write .NET applications with SQL Server for free, meaning without buying Visual Studio and SQL Server.

As long as you buy Windows web hosting (w/ support for .NET and SQL Server), is there software tools you can use to develop for free (Visual Web Developer?  SQL Express?)

Comment: It seems like that you already have the answers.

Visual Studio Express is free. SQL Server Express is free.

Comment: But can those be used for commercial use (along with paid web hosting)?

Comment: You want the Express versions of Visual Web Developer etc. Though this question is a duplicate.

Comment: Yes they can be used for commercial use. There's no restrictions on what you can do with the applications you develop.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are free versions of almost all of Microsoft's development software.

Most of them are called 'Express', such as Visual Studio Express, which are free.

Free to download, free to redistribute, free to embed, and easy for new developers to use immediately, SQL Server Express includes powerful features such as SQL Server Management Studio Express, for easily managing a database.
[Link to SQL Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/express.aspx)

.

Microsoft Visual Studio Express is a set of freeware integrated development environments (IDE) developed by Microsoft that are lightweight versions of the Microsoft Visual Studio product line. Express Editions were conceived beginning with Visual Studio 2005.
[Visual Studio Express and other Express products](http://www.microsoft.com/express/)

Comment: And there is free TFS too this time around!!

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Express and SQL Express

Answer (score 0):

The express editions of the software you're calling is free of charge.

You can get them from http://www.microsoft.com/express/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mono-project.com/  with their [CSharp Compiler](http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler)

It will also save your money on windows hosting ;-)